# Trigger click of an element on the basis of a button using JavaScript code in HTML markup and/or attribute(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger click on an icon(image) with specific class/id using onclick (or using any other way) of another button. Please see image for reference. Clicking "1" should trigger "2". Currently I am calling a javascript function "launchTopWM" which use following code to trigger click:

```
$(".custom_toggle_menu_default").trigger("click");
```

But i am wondering if i can call this code or perform this fucntionality using its click etc, something like `href='javascript:$(".custom_toggle_menu_default").trigger("click");'`

***Following is the Code:***

**HTML 1:**

```
 <img class="custom_toggle_menu_default" src="cc/tt/uu/images/launchTopWM.png">
```

**HTML 2:**

```
<a id="tsp" class="sp" href="launchTopWM()">CNw</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the code you have tried with the HTML as well.

Comment: I have uploaded image https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTr73.png. It contain visual elements along with sample Markup and Javascript code.

Comment: Please embed the image - indeed, *all* relevant information - in the question. That way people don't have to click to external files just to understand your question.

Comment: Markup is supposed to be posted as code on your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an id to the element and show the second anchor through pure javascript.

```html
<!DOCTPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title> Button style </title>
     <style>

     </style>
</head>
<body>


<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getElementById('button').click()" > click me </a>
<button id="button">  Buton </button>


    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $('#button').click(function(){
           alert('Buttons has been clicked');
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very nice example but you are setting "display" attribute and i need to trigger "click" of another icon.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger example, Hope it will give you the idea

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Triggger</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="tiggerCall">Trigger Focus</button>
<input type="text" placeholder="Onclick Call Focus" value=''>
<script>
$( "#tiggerCall" ).click(function() {
  $( "input" ).trigger( "focus" );
});
$( "input" ).focus(function() {
  $( "<span>Text box clicked</span>" ).appendTo( "body" ).fadeOut( 1000 );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```